# Using range-based for loop with CGAL types

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, cgal

Consider a `CGAL::Arrangement_2`. Right now, I have to iterate through it like this:

```
using MyArrangement = CGAL::Arrangement_2<MyTraits, MyDcel>;
for(MyArrangement::Face_handle face = map.faces_begin(); face != map.faces_end(); ++face)
{
    do_stuff(face);
}
```

If I try to migrate this to using a C++11-style range-based `for` loop like this:

```
for(auto face : gMap)
{
    do_stuff(face)
}
```

I get the following error (emphasis mine):

> Error:(1385, 13) invalid range expression of type 'CGAL::Arrangement_2 > >, true>, std::__1::vector > >, true> >, std::__1::allocator > >, true> > > >, CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2 > >, true> >, int> >, CGAL::Arr_extended_dcel > >, true>, std::__1::vector > >, true> >, std::__1::allocator > >, true> > > >, CGAL::Arr_consolidated_curve_data_traits_2 > >, true> >, int> >, GIS_vertex_data, GIS_halfedge_data, GIS_face_data, CGAL::Arr_vertex_base > >, true> > >, CGAL::Gps_halfedge_base > >, true> >, CGAL::_Unique_list > >, CGAL::Gps_face_base> >'; **no viable 'begin' function available**

The error is the same if I change the for loop to use `auto &face` or `const auto &face`.

Does anyone have a workaround for this, or some nice wrapper to make it work? I'm trying to avoid having to resort to using this monstrosity with a lambda argument:

```
template<typename F>
void for_each_face(MyArrangement &map, F callback)
{
    for(MyArrangement::Face_handle f = map.faces_begin(); f != map.faces_end(); ++f) 
    {
        callback(f); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You could implement an [overload for `std::begin` and `std::end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin). But I do not know if that class exposes other useful iterators.

Comment: Just don't put them in `std`.  Make them free functions as ADL should them.

Comment: Thanks for that correction. TIL about ADL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range base version to iterate over faces is [`face_handles()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/classArrangementDcel.html#a73ed32a916f6a4ca761548c293b92c75). You have similar functions for vertices(`vertex_handles()`), and halfedges (`halfedge_handles()`).

Comment: Aha! Thanks so much for the pointer. For the sake of posterity, it looks like this was introduced in CGAL 4.11, released in September 2017.